# Using pytables with python3 fails

Tags: python-3.x, pytables, pickle

importing pytables (3.1.1) in python 3.4.1 fails for me, complaining about a failed cPickle import
i try to use potables (3.1.1) with python (3.4.1)

```
In [1]: import tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-389ecae14f10> in <module>()
----> 1 import tables

/work/projects/vEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
     80 
     81 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 82 from tables.utilsextension import (
     83     get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version, blosc_compressor_list,
     84     blosc_compcode_to_compname_ as blosc_compcode_to_compname,

/work/projects/vEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.pyx in init tables.utilsextension (tables/utilsextension.c:15600)()

/work/projects/vEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables/description.py in <module>()
     22 import numpy
     23 
---> 24 from tables import atom
     25 from tables.path import check_name_validity
     26 

/work/projects/vEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tables/atom.py in <module>()
     18 import sys
     19 import inspect
---> 20 import cPickle
     21 
     22 import numpy
```

As i understand cPickle is only used instead of pickle in python2.
As of PyTable 3.x it should work fine with python3.x. How can there be a cPickle import than?

What do i have to do to use pytables with python3?

Answer (score 0):

The error was produced most likely due to a problem with my vEnv. Uninstalling the package and reinstalling it fix the problem.

See [github issue](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/365)